# What is the correct code in OR SqLite Android? Code not working

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite

I'm working with Sqlite Database in my app. I want to search a word and return all results that i search from NAME and REGION.

The search is working fine when my code is searching only in NAME but when using OR only with the function LIKE is working.

I tried using OR and || but it is not working.

```
fun getWords(wordPrefix: String = ""): Cursor {
    return if(wordPrefix.isBlank()) {
        readableDatabase.query(DatabaseEntryContract.TABLE_NAME, null,
                null, null, null, null,
                "${DatabaseEntryContract.COLUMN_NAME} ASC")
    } else {
        readableDatabase.query(DatabaseEntryContract.TABLE_NAME, null,
                "${DatabaseEntryContract.COLUMN_NAME} || ${DatabaseEntryContract.COLUMN_REGION} LIKE?", arrayOf("$wordPrefix%"),
                null, null,
                "${DatabaseEntryContract.COLUMN_NAME} ASC")
    }
}
```

I expect the Output to search in either NAME and REGION. for example if I input A in the search bar.

The results should be show all prefix with A in the NAME and REGION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :-

```
fun getWords(wordPrefix: String = ""): Cursor {
    return if(wordPrefix.isBlank()) {
        readableDatabase.query(DatabaseEntryContract.TABLE_NAME, null,
                null, null, null, null,
                "${DatabaseEntryContract.COLUMN_NAME} ASC")
    } else {
        readableDatabase.query(DatabaseEntryContract.TABLE_NAME, null,
                "${DatabaseEntryContract.COLUMN_NAME} LIKE? OR ${DatabaseEntryContract.COLUMN_REGION} LIKE?",
                arrayOf("$wordPrefix%","$wordPrefix%"),
                null, null,
                "${DatabaseEntryContract.COLUMN_NAME} ASC")
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir what if I want to search not only the first word of the column but should also any word or letter inside the column. What should i change?

Comment: @Gumangan `"%$wordPrefix%"` i.e **`%`** is a wild character so before and after the search item and the search item can then be anywhere.